# phpSPO Library - Unathorized access exception. Need guidance with library basics

Tags: php

I'm working with phpSPO library for work with sharePooint in a PHP app. https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO

I am trying to get to grips with the basics and I have to admit I am failing.

I have been looking at the various examples and searching the web for some 'complete' working examples and can find 'bits' of examples, but no complete working solution or guide that I can get into a test set and expand (learn) with.

The test set code I have so far is

```
<?php
    namespace Office365;

    spl_autoload_register(function ($classname) {
        $classname = ltrim($classname, "\\");
        preg_match('/^(.+)?([^\\\\]+)$/U', $classname, $match);
        $classname = './'.str_replace("\\", "/", $match[1])
            .str_replace(array("\\", "_"), "/", $match[2])
            .".php";
        include_once $classname;
    });

    use Office365\Runtime\Auth\ClientCredential;
    use Office365\SharePoint\ClientContext;
    use Office365\SharePoint\ListItem;

    $credentials = new ClientCredential("myusername", "myusersecret");
    $client = (new ClientContext("https://mydomain.sharepoint.com"))->withCredentials($credentials);

    $web = $client->getWeb();
    $list = $web->getLists()->getByTitle("test"); //init List resource
    $items = $list->getItems();  //prepare a query to retrieve from the 
    $client->load($items);  //save a query to retrieve list items from the server 
    $client->executeQuery(); //submit query to SharePoint server
    /** @var ListItem $item */
    foreach($items as $item) {
            print "Task: {$item->getProperty('Title')}\r\n";
    }

?>
```

Ideally an idiot guide to get this working so that I can learn from there would be great.

So far the above code has got me the following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Office365\Runtime\Http\RequestException: {"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"}}}`

So it looks like 'something' is happening but I am drawing a blank. I have run out of skill/information.

Comment: `Access is denied` Check your credentials

Comment: `ClientCredential` expects `"{clientId}", "{clientSecret}"`. If you want to use username and pwd then try with `UserCredentials`

Comment: I was thinking that there might be some confusion regarding the credentials because the access is from a subdomain of the parent. When I created the credentials I used the  subdomain in the 'App Domain' field. Is there something I am missing (fundamental) here?

Comment: I am using clientId, ClientSecret. My bad terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete working PHP testset.

My phpSPO library from Github was downloaded into a folder called Office365in my root directory of my web site

The following works as a test set:

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function ($classname) {
    $classname = ltrim($classname, "\\");
    preg_match('/^(.+)?([^\\\\]+)$/U', $classname, $match);
    $classname = './'.str_replace("\\", "/", $match[1])
        .str_replace(array("\\", "_"), "/", $match[2])
        .".php";
    include_once $classname;
});


use Office365\Runtime\Auth\ClientCredential;
use Office365\SharePoint\ClientContext;
use Office365\SharePoint\Web;

$credentials = new ClientCredential("myclientid", "myclientsecret");
$ctx = (new ClientContext("https://powernaturally.sharepoint.com"))->withCredentials($credentials);


$folderName = "Test_" . rand(1, 100000);
$rootFolder = $ctx->getWeb()->getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Shared Documents");
$newFolder = $rootFolder->getFolders()->add($folderName)->executeQuery();
print($newFolder->getServerRelativeUrl());

?>
```

It writes a new folder to 'Shared Document'